# Matrix Palette, Drawing Issue when ModelView Matrix

Tags: android, opengl-es

Using OpenGL 1.1 and the Matrix Palette extension. The issue I'm having, is that not every model being loaded needs to be animated, so I don't think that I need to enable those client states nor provide weights or weight index arrays. For example, I'm trying something like this during my drawing code...

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MATRIX_PALETTE_OES);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataBuffers[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataBuffers[1]);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_WEIGHT_ARRAY_OES);
glEnableClientState(GL_MATRIX_INDEX_ARRAY_OES);

//Code to modify the palettes... works fine...
for(i = 0; i < mech.boneCount; ++i){
    glCurrentPaletteMatrixOES(i);
    glLoadPaletteFromModelViewMatrixOES();

    GenerateBoneMatrixPalette(bones, i);
}

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(VertexData), (char*)(NULL + 0));
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(VertexData), (char*)(NULL + 12));
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sizeof(VertexData), (char*)(NULL + 24));
glWeightPointerOES(1, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(VertexData), (char*)(NULL + 28));
glMatrixIndexPointerOES(1, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sizeof(VertexData), (char*)(NULL + 32));
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mech.indexsize, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (char*)(NULL + 0));

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_WEIGHT_ARRAY_OES);
glDisableClientState(GL_MATRIX_INDEX_ARRAY_OES);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataBuffers[2]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataBuffers[3]);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

//pardon the hard 28 value here, it's the correct offset for this test
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 28, (char*)(NULL + 0));
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 28, (char*)(NULL + 12));
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 28, (char*)(NULL + 24));
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexsize, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (char*)(NULL + 0));

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

But it is not working. The first section displays correctly but the second does not display at all. If I add an, what feels to be, unnecessary weight and weight index element to the second section modifying the stride as needed and not setting the matrix to the modelview... then it displays what I expect.

The test that feels the strangest, is if I do not enable the Matrix Palette extension at all and only draw the second part, it works just fine. However, just enabling the Matrix Palette extension causes the second section to not work at all, making it seem that I can not draw simply while the mode is set to the ModelView Matrix... though this seems somewhat unusual as the ModelView still absolutely is affected by transformations.

So... is it possible to switch to and draw while the ModelView is the current matrix while using this extension? Or must I make use/reuse a single palette to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found an OES matrix palette extension in the extension registry, but an ARB extension and suppose it works similar. In this extension, you have to enable `GL_MATRIX_PALETTE` and or `GL_VERTEX_BLEND` (with `glEnable`) to use matrix palette skinning and disable it to not use it.

But the glMatrixMode does't have anything to do with enabling or disabling it. It just selects the matrix to which matrix modification functions apply (like `glLoadIdentity`, `glTranslate`, ...).

**EDIT:** After googling this extension (I have no ES experience) I found, that you definitely have to enable `GL_MATRIX_PALETTE_OES` to use it (via `glEnable`) and then **disable it again** for your second part to not use it. As I've written above, `glMatrixMode` doesn't do what you thought it to.

Comment: The OES implementation of the ARB extension is very similar, but doesn't have all the same functionality of it (for instance you can not get the current matrix). Still, if it is a matter of enabling and disabling I will give it a try. Would you know if there is a lot of overhead in enabling/disabling this on the fly?

Comment: To follow up... yes this did work. I'll have to ultimately run some performance tests to see which is more of an issue, more memory for the weights/weight indices or the extra gl calls. Thanks again.

Comment: @Maximus I doubt, just disabling matrix palette skinning is more expensive than transfering unused skinning data for every object, not to speek of the heavier vertex processing with enabled skinning. So just disabling it should be the method of choice. You could also sort your objects by state.

Comment: yes to that last part, I would intend fully on drawing all models requiring palettes, then disabling that extension and drawing the rest. Thanks again!

Comment: @Maximus But don't forget, that your models also may have other important state. In that case I'd rather sort them by texture/material than by skinning.