# When to call glDisableClientState() while using VBOs

Tags: opengl-es

Sorry for what feels like a bit of an ignorant question, but all the examples I can find only draw from one buffer, so I can't get an answer to this one.

Which is correct?

```
Enable Client States
Bind
Draw
Bind
Draw
Bind to 0
Disable Client States
```

or

```
Bind
Enable Client States
Draw
Disable Client States
Bind
Enable Client States
Draw
Disable Client States
Bind to 0
```

or something else?

In short, what is the correct order for making multiple draw calls with multiple vbos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should both work, though the first will involve fewer API calls/state changes.  I'm a little leery in your second sequence of binding before the relevant client enable though.

If you're using the same client states throughout your program you can get by with enabling them at the start and leaving them enabled throughout.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. Any idea on my other recent post by any chance? I noticed you had an edit on it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106152/matrix-palette-drawing-issue-when-modelview-matrix I'd like to know that I'll be able to use different ClientStates if necessary and feel I shouldn't have to include weights if they aren't needed.

Comment: Although your last statement is correct, enabling them at the start could be a bit error prone, as array state is heavily object-specific.